# What is this plugin (or widget) in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I searched google but no working.

Please give me the documentation link.

Thank you in advance.

Appreciate any useful answer.

[image]

[The link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap 'ScrollSpy' component changes the style of the sidebar menu items as the page is scrolled. When an item is activated based on the current page scroll position, the 'active' CSS class is added to the sidebar menu item `<li>`. So the actual left-border style on the active item is done with CSS, for example:

```
#sidebar li.active {
    border:0 #eee solid;
    border-right-width:4px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/Q8tDns7ON1

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it with a variation of [Bootstrap Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Answer (score 1):

It is called Scroll Spy. It is part of the Bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

It is actually quite simple to implement, once you loaded the Bootstrap JS

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
  ...
  <div id="navbar-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

They use those media queries in the Less files to create the key breakpoints in the grid system. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries